# Running into error coercing data.frame to numerical values

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, multiplication

I have a data.frame titled "matched_SNPs" here:

```
  SNP               ACB               ASW               BEB          EFF
rs10007883 0.536458333333333 0.549180327868853 0.191860465116279    -0.005748
rs10009522 0.604166666666667 0.475409836065574 0.162790697674419     0.008854
rs10010325 0.458333333333333 0.467213114754098 0.453488372093023    -0.006217
rs10010809             0.375 0.401639344262295 0.290697674418605     0.005879
rs10015151 0.572916666666667 0.442622950819672 0.546511627906977    -0.005789
rs10016978            0.5625 0.565573770491803 0.424418604651163    -0.005444
```

I wanted to make a new dataframe that is based off the values of columns 2, 3, and 4, multiplied by column 5, that is formatted like this:

```
ACB   ASW   BEB
value value value
value value value
value value value
value value value
```

I have tried 
`new_df=(as.numeric(as.character(matched_SNPs[,2:4]))*as.numeric(as.character(matched_SNPs$EFF)))`

```
but all I get is: Warning messages:
1: NAs introduced by coercion 
2: In as.numeric(as.character(matched_SNPs[, 2:4])) * as.numeric(as.character(matched_SNPs$EFF)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I have also tried the more basic `weighted_freqs=(matched_SNPs[,2:27])*(matched_SNPs$EFF)`, but I get a warning message that says that `In Ops.factor(left, right) : '*' not meaningful for factors`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simply do the multiplication

```
matched_SNPs[2:4] * matched_SNPs[,5]
#      ACB          ASW          BEB
#1 -0.003083562 -0.003156689 -0.001102814
#2  0.005349292  0.004209279  0.001441349
#3 -0.002849458 -0.002904664 -0.002819337
#4  0.002204625  0.002361238  0.001709012
#5 -0.003316615 -0.002562344 -0.003163756
#6 -0.003062250 -0.003078984 -0.002310535
```

assuming that the columns are `numeric`

If it is not `numeric` and is `factor` then convert the columns of interest to `numeric` first and then do the multiplication

```
matched_SNPs[2:5] <- lapply(matched_SNPs[2:5], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Comment: This works, out of curiosity, why did my line of code converting them to numeric not work?

Comment: @Evan The `as.numeric/as.character` works on vector and not on data.frame.  That is the reason we are looping on each column

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyverse` approach

Load the library:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Perform the multiplication and select only the three variables you need:

```
mydf_molt <- mydf %>% 
    mutate_at(.vars=c("ACB","ASW","BEB"),.funs=funs(.*EFF)) %>% 
    select(ACB,ASW,BEB)
```

This is the output:

```
           ACB          ASW          BEB
1 -0.003083562 -0.003156689 -0.001102814
2  0.005349292  0.004209279  0.001441349
3 -0.002849458 -0.002904664 -0.002819337
4  0.002204625  0.002361238  0.001709012
5 -0.003316615 -0.002562344 -0.003163756
6 -0.003062250 -0.003078984 -0.002310535
```